# why would you shuffle the test dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, dataset

I fully understand the use of a training set separate from the test set.

I also understand why you would shuffle batches in the training set to compute the gradient over mini-batches.

However, ads mentioned in the [pyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html), I do not understand why you would use a shuffling of the test set like in:

```
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

In what case would that be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shuffled my test set due to batch wise statistics. I was computing the [roc_auc_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) for each batch. I was doing a binary classification task and positive and negative examples were loaded from different locations on the disk. The generated file list was therefore something like `[0,0,0,1,1,1]` when looking at the classes. Without shuffling it can then happen that you only have one class in a batch and the batchwise score computation fails. I shuffled it therefore but got a warning that it is strongly recommended to not do so. As a matter of fact i observed randomness in summary statistics whenever i rerun the model on the test set. Thanks to the first poster I assume I now know why.

Answer (score 1):

No need in most cases as you don't update the weights.

Hard to come up with an example, but batch-dependent statistics might be one - e.g. mean accuracy across batches.

Still, I have never seen such a thing and one could argue (and I’d agree) that shuffling test dataset introduces unnecessary randomness (if anything) and makes comparisons less reliable (in the example above) between epochs.